# How to solve TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, openerp-7

I am trying to retrieve a list in my database. My statement is this:

```
cr.execute("select es.* from student_resource es where es.date between '"+str(date_from)+"' and '"+str(date_to)+"'")
```

where **date_from** and **date_to** are of type **fields.date** but when when executed, that is i am trying to access my view, it says:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

What did I miss with my statement?

LOG:

```
File "/opt/openerp/server-7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/custom_addons/sample_new/student_resource.py", line 207, in generate_ewt_line
    from student_resource es where es.date between '"+str(date_from.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))+"' and '"+str(date_to.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))+"'\
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

This is what I get.

**EDIT**

This is actually what I am doing:

```
_logger.info("\n\t\t\tI was called. My method name is %s"%(str('generate_student_resource_report')))
for ewt in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context):
    old_history = resource_line_obj.search(cr, uid, [('parent_id','=',ewt.id)],context=context)
    if old_history:
       ewt_line_obj.unlink(cr, uid, old_history,context=context)   
    cr.execute("insert into resource_line(partner_id,seq,base_amount,tax_amount,percent,atc_code,\
                    nature,parent_id,create_date,write_date,create_uid, write_uid)\
                select es.part_id as partner_id,\
                    (case when es.name like '%WC158%' then 1\
                        when es.name like '%WC160%' then 2\
                        when es.name like '%WC010%' then 3\
                        when es.name like '%WC140%' then 4\
                        else 0 end) as seq,\
                    sum(es.base_amt) as base_amount,\
                    sum(es.tax_amt) as tax_amount,\
                    (case when es.name like '%EWT 1\%%' then '1.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 2\%%' then '2.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 3\%%' then '3.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 4\%%' then '4.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 5\%%' then '5.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 6\%%' then '6.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 7\%%' then '7.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 8\%%' then '8.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 9\%%' then '9.00'\
                        when es.name like '%EWT 10\%%' then '10.00'\
                        else null end) as percent,\
                    (case when es.name like '%WC158%' then 'WC158'\
                        when es.name like '%WC160%' then 'WC160'\
                        when es.name like '%WC010%' then 'WC010'\
                        when es.name like '%WC140%' then 'WC140'\
                        else null end) as atc_code,\
                    (case when es.name like '%WC158%' then 'NOTEBOOK'\
                        when es.name like '%WC160%' then 'BACKPACK'\
                        when es.name like '%WC010%' then 'COLOR'\
                        when es.name like '%WC140%' then 'BOOKS' else null end) as nature,\
                    (now()) as create_date,(now()) as write_date,\
                     ? as parent_id,? as create_uid,? as write_uid\
                from student_source es where es.date between ? and ? \
                group by es.partner_id,es.name",(ewt.id,uid,uid,str(date_from),str(date_to)))
    line_list = cr.fetchall()
    _logger.info("\n\t\t\tSource ... %s"%(str(line_list)))   
    list = self.pool.get('student.resource.line').search(cr,uid,[('parent_id','=',ewt.id)])
    lines = [line.id if line.id else False for line in self.pool.get('student.resource.line').browse(cr,uid,list,context=context)]
value = {
         "value" : {
                    'name' : 'Student Resources Report',
                    "ewt_line" : lines
                    }
         }
return value
```

Comment: You appear to be building an SQL query by concatenation, which is very bad form - try reading the documentation for the tool you're using to understand how to do it properly.

Comment: When i use it on postgres it work fine i don't know why it produce an error when using on eclipse.

Comment: @AnirudhLou are you certain that the error is in this very line? Care to share the full trace? Besides, what's said about concatenation in the comment above is really worth paying attention.

Comment: The fact that it's worked before is immaterial; it's not the appropriate way to do this. I suggest you start by looking into Python's database API (see e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) - you should be providing the arguments separately to the actual query and letting the database engine insert them appropriately. This helps protect you against e.g. SQL injection attacks, and makes your code easier to read. This may not solve your problem, but will hopefully make it easier to provide an [mcve] with no other issues in.

Comment: If you need to know why it's not safe to build an SQL query by concatenation please ask [Mrs Roberts](https://xkcd.com/327). Also see http://bobby-tables.com/python.html

Comment: You should use [ORM methods](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#common-orm-methods) in that case instead of string concatenation

Comment: I've tried this one:  `from ewt_source es where es.date between ? and ? group by es.partner_id,es.name",(str(date_from),str(date_to)))`. But it says: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Yes, you are right, and if you run queries with `cr.execute` are faster. But if you run the queries like that the orm `_constraints` are ignored. You must be sure that all the constraints are defined as `_sql_constraints`

Comment: @AnirudhLou could you post that in your question and give sample of date_from and date_to

Comment: Yes, maybe we can give a better solution if we know how you declared both variables or if we know the whole method

Comment: I updated my question, i mean it's description.

Comment: With that case, why it returns tuple index out of range?

Answer (score 1):

You should [ORM methods](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#common-orm-methods). Try something like this:

```
student_resource_obj = self.pool.get('student.resource')
lines = student_resource_obj.search(cr, uid,
    [('date', '>', date_from), 
    ('date', '<', date_to)]
)
for record in lines:
    # [...]
```

Comment: I'm sorry,  my ORM-remark was wrong, didn't notice the OpenERP reference. I cannot cancel the downvote unless you edit your answer somehow (like, by adding the verb into the first sentence :) ).

Comment: i have updated my body's question. Actually, i had also asked related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065162/how-to-get-the-sum-of-field-in-a-column but in that code i used python and i cannot get the sum/total.

Comment: By the way, I updated my question to adapt it to OpenERP v7. The type of the `date` field is `fields.date()` right?

Comment: Yes it is. But as I've said I cannot get the sum of those fields that s why I tried it using SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **?** sign from query instead use **%s** and at last remove **,** and replace it with **%(ewt.date_from,ewt.date_to))**

in short query looks like,

```
qry = "select * from table where field1 = %s and field2=%s" %(value1, value2)
cr.execute(qry)
```

And you date conversion looks like,

```
cr.execute("select es.* from student_resource es where es.date between '"+ date_from.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +"' and '"+ date_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +"'")
```